# Fetching remote upstream in GIT

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control, gitlab

I am new to GitHub and its a little confusing to get my head through upstream and local changes. Here is my situation. any advice is really appreciated.

I forked a git repository and I have my upstream and my origin set now.

if i type below command

```
git remote -v 

This gives me 2 repositories 
origin (points to my forked path)
upstream (points to my parent project path)
```

now, here is the confusion. If i go to GitHub and see the branches. It shows `master` and `develop` branch. And if i check the link for these 2, its identical. so how do you differentiate which is develop branch and which is master branch.

Now, here is my thing. If i check the branches at my local. I only see a master branch. I cannot work directly on the master branch. I have to work on the develop branch and push changes to develop branch of parent.

I tried these steps

```
git checkout -b develop (From the local master branch)
git pull upstream/develop.
```

Now does this mean, i have pulled all my changes from upstream's develop branch into the develop  branch of local ? this is confusing  :(

Now when i am in my local develop branch, i created a feature branch from it by using below command

```
git checkout -b "feature1"
```

Now i work on the changes and push the changes for Peer review by typing below commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "feature added"
git push -u origin feature1
```

At this moment, i have pushed the PR in GITHUB. I go to github and raise the PR to merge from my branch to upstream develop branch. Changes are merged in now.

Now i go back to the local develop branch from my feature branch by using below command

```
git checkout develop
```

How do i pull this latest changes which i just merged to upstream develop to local's develop branch . Because if i try anything, i am still not able to get my recent change which i updated in upstream develop.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout -b <some branch>` creates locally new branch on top of current HEAD.

If the branch is already there don't create it just switch to it and it will be already connected to upstream branch.

```sh
git clone <my repo>
# assumming you will be on master branch after clone just switch to develop
git checkout develop
# just pull recent changes anytime something new could appear on origin
git pull
```

if you already created local `develop` you can always delete it and just switch again to non-existing develop which will try to pull it first from origin:

```sh
# let's say we are on local develop then go to another branch
git checkout master
# delete local develop
git branch -D develop
# switch to develop should checkout develop which will be tracking origin develop
git checkout develop
# and again if sth new appears on origin just pull it
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch to `develop` branch on your local machine execute:

```
git checkout develop
```

Once you are on `develop` branch, confirm the same using:

```
git branch
```

The above command should highlight `develop` branch.
Once the PR has been merged, simply execute:

```
git pull origin develop
```

This will pull the merged remote changes (from `develop`) to your local (`develop`) branch.